# Unir en una misma tabla en una consulta mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola intento unir de una sola tabla dos consultas, tengo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT ppl.id_product,ppl.id_lang, ppl.name, ppl.description_short from ps_product_lang ppl;
```

esa consulta me arroja el siguiente resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el id_lang es el idioma, donde 1 es español y 2 es inglés, bueno lo que quiero lograr es lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
que no se hagan dos líneas por el id_lang sino poder hacerlo en una sola línea ¿es posible? he estado buscando pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo, agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola muchas gracias por el apoyo, pude solucionar mi problema con la siguiente consulta:

```
 SELECT t1.id_product,t1.id_lang AS Inglés, t1.name, t1.description_short, t2.id_product, t2.id_lang AS Español, t2.name, t2.description_short
FROM (
SELECT id_product,id_lang, name, description_short FROM ps_product_lang WHERE id_lang='1'
) t1
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT id_product,id_lang, name, description_short FROM ps_product_lang WHERE id_lang='2'
)t2 ON t1.id_product = t2.id_product;
```

Answer (score 1):

Entonces te propongo que hagas un **inner join** hacia la misma tabla:

```
select  *
from (
      select *
      from ps_product_lang
      where idLang = 1
     ) ppl
inner join ps_product_lang ppl2 on ppl.id = ppl2.id
where idLang = 2;
```

Este ejemplo es genérico, analizalo y adáptalo a tu código.

Lo que se hace es relacionar la misma tabla pero filtrando primero para un idioma y después para otro.
La **cláusula select** dentro de la **cláusula from** devuelve un conjunto de resultados por lo que puede tratarse como si ese conjunto devuelto fuese una tabla.

Answer (score 0):

Es un poco confuso como lo describes, pero creo seria algo mas o menos así:

```
Select *
(Select tabla.id AS 'ID01', tabla.dato AS 'Datox1' from tabla where tabla.id = 1) 
TablaX1
LEFT JOIN
(Select tabla.id AS 'ID02' , tabla.dato AS 'Datox2' from tabla where tabla.id = 2) 
TablaX2 ON TablaX1.Datox1 = TablaX2.Datox2
```

Answer (score 0):

Dato que todos los registros están en una misma tabla, lo ideal seria crear un pivot, pero también se puede lograr con con sub-querys (no es lo ideal), este sería el query que necesitas:

```
select  ppl.id_product, 
        ppl.id_lang, 
        ppl.name, 
        ppl.description_short,  
        (select eng.id_lang FROM ps_product_lang  as eng WHERE eng.id_product = ppl.id_product AND eng.id_lang = 2) as id_lang_eng, 
        (select eng.name FROM ps_product_lang  as eng WHERE eng.id_product = ppl.id_product AND eng.id_lang = 2) as name_eng, 
        (select eng.description_short FROM ps_product_lang  as eng WHERE eng.id_product = ppl.id_product AND eng.id_lang = 2) as description_short_eng  
FROM    ps_product_lang  ppl where ppl.id_lang = 1;
```

Ene la consulta principal filtramos todos los registros con lang 1 y agregamos como sub-querys los que tienen lang 2

**Edit 1:**

Puedes lograr un mejor resultado con join y puedes agregar mas lenguajes si fuera necesario haciendo un join a la misma tabla:

```
select  ppl.id_product, 
        ppl.id_lang, 
        ppl.name, 
        ppl.description_short,          
        ppl_eng.id_lang as id_lang_eng, 
        ppl_eng.name  as name_eng, 
        ppl_eng.description_short as description_short_eng
FROM    ps_product_lang as ppl 
        join ps_product_lang as ppl_eng on ( ppl.id_product = ppl_eng.id_product AND ppl_eng.id_lang = 2)
where   ppl.id_lang = 1;
```

Comment: Yo lo solucionaría obteniendo el resultado como está, uno debajo de otro, y una vez obtenido, recorrer los resultados, supongamos con php e ir concatenando las líneas. No se, cual es el objetivo de obtener los resultados uno al lado de otro?